# Align in different depths

Tags: align

I've been trying to make a diagram that looks as follows for example

[image]

Basically, I want to use the align environment with different depths. It would easily work if I had to indent once, but how can you create multiple depths?

Comment: tray with `alignedat`; `\begin{alignedat}{5} ... \end{alignedat}`. Or wit simple `array`.

Comment: You could use an array environment, although is adds a gap (\arraycolsep?) between columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with TikZ. Use `fresh nodes` to allow duplicate labels, and use empty labels and edges as filler. Reasonable concise, I think.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[fresh nodes]{
    A -> B -> C -> D -> E;
    {""} -!- -> B -> C -> D -> E;
    {""} -!- {""} -!- C -> D -> E;
    {""} -!- B -> C -> D -> E;
    {""} -!- {""} -!- {""} -!- D -> E;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 1):

With rows denoted as

```
A & B & C & D & E \\
```

you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{rdiagram}{b}
 {
  \gerlach_rdiagram:n { #1 }
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_rows_seq
\seq_new:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_row_seq
\int_new:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_cols_int
\tl_new:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gerlach_rdiagram:n
 {
  % reset the counter
  \int_zero:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_cols_int
  % split into rows
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__gerlach_rdiagram_rows_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  % check for a trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__gerlach_rdiagram_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_tmpa_tl
   {
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__gerlach_rdiagram_rows_seq \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  % count the number of cells
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__gerlach_rdiagram_rows_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__gerlach_rdiagram_row_seq { & } { ##1 }
    \int_compare:nT { \seq_count:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_row_seq > \l__gerlach_rdiagram_cols_int }
     {
      \int_set:Nn \l__gerlach_rdiagram_cols_int { \seq_count:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_row_seq }
     }
   }
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \tl_clear:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_body_tl
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__gerlach_rdiagram_rows_seq \__gerlach_rdiagram_row:n
  \begin{array}{ c *{\int_eval:n { \l__gerlach_rdiagram_cols_int - 1 }}{>{{}}c<{{}}c} }
  \tl_use:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_body_tl
  \end{array}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gerlach_rdiagram_row:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__gerlach_rdiagram_row_seq { & } { #1 }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__gerlach_rdiagram_body_tl
   {
    \prg_replicate:nn
     { \l__gerlach_rdiagram_cols_int - \seq_count:N \l__gerlach_rdiagram_row_seq }
     { && }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__gerlach_rdiagram_row_seq { & \rightarrow & }
    \exp_not:N \\
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\[
\begin{rdiagram}
A & B & C & D & E \\
    B & C & D & E \\
    B & C & D & E \\
        C & D & E \\
    B & C & D & E \\
    B & C & D & E \\
            D & E
\end{rdiagram}
\]
\lipsum[2][1-5]

\end{document}
```

The idea is to split the body into rows and, for each row, to count the number of `&` separated items. This is used to set up the number of columns in an `array` and then to use it in order to add the suitable number of `&&`; the `&` are instead replaced by `&\rightarrow&`.

[image]